# Connecting Component Manager with Marketplace Account

Tags: marketplace, foreign-key, component-manager, magento2-enterprise

We just created an instance of a 2.1 EE version. Everything works well and seems to work. But when we try to sign in into the component manager with our Magento account we get a RuntimeException with the following error (using wrong credentials specifically gives us a bad credentials warning):

```
Message:
Couldn't get available versions for package magento/framework-foreign-key
```

We didn't change any code yet. Does any know how we can proceed?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: No, but we also didn't continue looking for a solution. But if you also using Magento EE contact the support and they definitely can fix it for you.